# Set single empty view for multiple Listview?

Tags: java, android, listview

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:id="@+id/count"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/empty1"
        android:text="No data"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:id="@+id/weatherl"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/empty2"
        android:text="No data"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:id="@+id/track"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/empty3"
        android:text="No data"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and In Java

```
 View empty1 = findViewById(R.id.empty1);
        countList.setEmptyView(empty1);
```

I'm able to set separate empty view for each list but I want single empty view for all list. If all listviews are empty, then i want to show message like 'No data' so, How to get single empty view for 2 or more listview?

Comment: add your code please

Comment: @Vahidhashemi added xml file please check

Comment: create your emptyView layout then use `include` keyword to include layout in each view that you want

Comment: In that case setVisibility for all ListView to GONE and show your message on **empty1** textview.

Comment: But how to check whether all list is empty or not? Please provide some code snippet if possible

Comment: @shayanpourvatan but included layout will show every time

Comment: you can use `View.VISIBLE` and `View.GONE` to show and hide it

Comment: @shayanpourvatan Yes, but how to check if all three list are empty or not?

Comment: how you fill data on lists? after getting data check other list data is loaded or not and if they loaded is data exists on those or not,

Comment: @shayanpourvatan Using Json, I've tried to check if list size is 0 but not working quitely